# Best algo for finding no. of steps required to convert a sequence to a palindromic sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question, pattern-recognition, mental-arithmetic

[My first question of Math SE, so, HI!]
I'm not sure of what the rules are around the place, but I have a straightforward question as follows...

> The sequences 23, 45, 23 and 23, 45, 56, 23, 23, 56, 45, 23 are
>   examples of palindromes. The sequence 23, 45, 56 is not a palindrome.
>   The sequence 23, 32 is not a palindrome either. A sequence of length 1
>   is always a palindrome. A given sequence of integers can be broken up
>   into parts such that each of them is a palindrome. Consider the
>   sequence 34,45,34,56,34. This can be broken up into 3 palindrome
>   sequences with 34, 45, 34 constituting the first, 56 constituting the
>   second and 34 constituting the third. It can also be broken in 5
>   palindrome sequences each containing a single number.
>
> We want to determine the smallest number K such that the given
>   sequence can be broken up into K palindrome sequences.

Comment: A subquadratic algorithm for minimum palindromic factorization: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1570866714000525

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche , no no, this is an extension of a  question I found in the book "The Algorithm Design Manual: by Steven Skiena", and I'll try asking there as well.

Comment: Can no one help me here ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  think about numbers that appear only once in the sequence. Then think again.

Comment: Haha, I've already thought about doing so, and that's easy if we do that manually but in terms of defining a formal algorithm for the problem, I'm failing using the method.
P.S. : I need a bigger hint :P

Comment: Where are you stuck?  All that matters is how many times each number appears, not what the numbers are.

Comment: what do you mean @rossmillikan

Comment: could you explain your algo a little better ? I mean, I don't think we're on the same page...

Comment: Note that in any given sequence, only the center number (if there is one) appears an odd number of times.